# Date/time picker standard?

Tags: html, datetime, datetimepicker

[Supposedly](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#type-date), HTML5 includes various date/time input types. But only Opera really supports them, though I've discovered Chrome has (very) limited support for them as well. Is this really an HTML5 standard? Do major browsers plan to support these input types ever?

(ignoring jQuery solutions to this problem, etc. I'm talking about browsers natively supporting date/time input types)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is in the HTML5 Working Draft:

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#date-and-time-state

Hence, we would expect the major browsers to support them in the future.

Comment: I feel fairly confident that I (personally) won't be abandoning javascript solutions to HTML5 validation or form widgets any time soon. It's pretty much impossible to control the UI using the HTML5 methods, and we're going to have to be backwards compatible for quite a while. It's certainly something to look forward to, some day...